# Designing a Circuit for Rotational Magnetic Field

Tags: ac, dc, inverter

I hope you're all doing well. I'm a beginner regarding building things like that which I’m going to explain now, so please include as much information as you think might help me. I want to create a circuit that transforms a 3.3V DC output from a microcontroller (ESP32) into an AC output. The goal is to power a set of three electromagnets, each consisting of spooled up copper wires, with the intention of generating a rotational magnetic field that can rotate a disk that contains n neodymium magnets.

Specifically, I'm wondering about the following:

1. **Circuit Design:** What would be the most suitable circuit design to achieve this transformation from DC to AC? I'm looking for recommendations on the type of components or modules that could be utilized for this purpose.
2. **AC Voltage Requirement:** What would be the correct AC voltage to effectively power the set of three electromagnets? I'm aware that the number of turns in the copper wire spools and the desired rotational speed might influence this, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.
   The plan is to start with attaching some rotors to that disk to generate a stream of air (like a fan).
3. **Synchronization:** Given that I want to create a rotational magnetic field, how should I synchronize the activation of the three electromagnets? Are there any timing considerations or specific methods I should explore?

Comment: A great learning project! I remember Atmel had full-on development kits with code and hardware for three phase inverters, mainly aimed for washing machines, but the code would be the same for small motors. This was pre-Arduino days. I'm sure you can find plenty of resources available online. As for synchronization, how much of an initial jerk can you accept at startup?

Comment: Thank you! I’m planning to mount it on a wooden plate so I guess it can tolerate quite a ome jerk. Besides that, I specifically will print parts in resin/pla so it will be quite strong.

Comment: If you can accept a small jerk, you can go sensorless and just sense the back-EMF. For a beginner project, it may be easier to have Hall sensor feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially creating a 3-phase motor controller.  In your case, the first thing to do is see if there is a chip that does the whole thing and there are quite a few.  The answer to your second question depends on how big you want the rotor to be, how fast you want it to turn, and how big the impeller you're planning on attaching to it is.

Comment: Can you tell me which chips can do that? 

The whole rotor will be quite small, maybe 5-7cm? I will print it from resin or PLA, so it will also be quite light. 


Ideally I would be able to control the turn speed via a parameter that I set in my microcontroller, however to start things, constant turning speed would be fine.

Comment: Specific product recommendations are not allowed here, but if you search "3-phase motor controller", you'll find some parts.  I do not recommend ordering anything from alibaba/ebay/amazon/et. al. since the documentation will likely be slim to nonexistent.  I suggest seeing if any of the Arduino hobbyist places have boards with the features you want since they usually include quickstart guides and additional documentation that would be helpful for a beginner.  There are also manufacturers' dev boards but they can be a bit pricey.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you and I can finally go to sleep now!

Answer (score 0):

Use a small computer fan that has a speed control input. This would be very cheap and save a ton of trouble. Cut the blades and most of the frame off to suit your application. The fans work pretty much in the way you describe. Some require pulse-width modulation (PWM) on the input to control the speed. Others might accept a variable DC voltage from a potentiometer.

Comment: I somehow want to learn this stuff, therefore I want to build it myself at least to some degree.

Comment: most of them are single phase

Comment: @Jasen, no most computer fans are DC supply with internal 3-phase motor and controller.

Comment: the one I've investigated most recently had a single phase DC motor.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні, then it would have to be a motor with carbon brushes. Was it? Here's a (not very good) YouTube video teardown: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o05Q5_OtURA&ab_channel=svetnovinek.cz.

Comment: no,  some sore of asymmetric single pole thing with a semiconductor switch, I can't find any images, maybe I hallucinated it.

Comment: If it was a single pole motor then it was probably a hallucination alright!